# Symfony and twig: too many fields in a form?

Tags: php, forms, performance, symfony, twig

I've got over 100 fields in a twig form, and it takes 2.5s and sometimes more just to display it. That's way to slow for modern users.

Is that just par for the course? I'm a Symfony newbie, but I'm not doing anything fancy. Even when I just use the default 3 line form, it takes ages.

Are there any clever ways to speed things up? I've searched here, and tried messsing with php.ini, and similar ideas, but nothing has helped so far.

I could chop the form into several, but then there's latency back and forth to the web server, to slow things down ever more ...

I'm using a fast PC with SSD and lots of RAM, and it's just as slow on a Mac as well :(

Any suggestions?

Maybe I'm just asking too much?

Maybe I should be using a faster web dev framework? If so, what? I want to stick with MVC if possible. Maybe something like Sails?

Comment: Without posting any code we can only guess what's wrong with your form. I must say, though, that having so many fields in a form is outrageous - you can't expect it to be lightning fast. In my experience, I've used Symfony Forms in ERP platforms with quite heavy business logic and still managed to keep the performance at reasonable levels. You are probably doing it wrong. Please post your code so we could help.

Comment: How big is your HTML, presumably > 1Mb or so?  I can't think it's a fundamental problem with Symfony or Twig causing your page to be slow, it's simply too large a file.

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using? [There were](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/16294) some performance improvement regarding the property access component, which the form component uses to access data. You should update to 2.8 at least and check if it helps a bit.

Comment: I'm guessing the slowness is related to the dev mode. Switch to prod and see if things speed up.

Comment: You got some choices... all the above comments might help you.

Comment: Thanks, guys! The HTML itself is 789kb, which is quite big. And yes there ARE far too many fields. I'm leaning towards chopping it up into a 3-4 part process, where each form leads onto the next one.

I'm usng Symfony v3, so hopefully, it's not an issue.

It's also slow in prod, which surprised me.

Yes, I might be doing something wrong, but I'm not doing anything fancy.

e.g. here's how I display fields:

{{ form_label(form.user.gender) }} <br/>
{{ form_widget(form.user.gender) }} <br/>
{{ form_errors(form.user.gender) }} <br/>

Really simple stuff! A little CSS, but under a page.

Comment: I'd like to just dump the code here, but it would be a hassle to munge what I need to keep private. Again, it's really simple stuff. I don't know enough to do anything fancy!

I include 3 twig forms, but again, that's simple stuff.

I use translations, but I doubt they are an issue. Only got English so far :)

As suggested, I might just have far too many fields in the same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a js script who create your form with your 100 filds
at the end , catch the respense with Symfony into a controller

Comment: Hmmm ... that sounds like it might work. Let symfony create a short form, and use Ajax to add all the other fields. That way, it loads quickly, and keeps loading the other fields in the background. Nice idea, thanks! Now I just need to figure out how to do it, as it doesn't sound simple.